# Is it possible to change resolution on Azure VM?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-vm

we are using Azure VM with Windows to run our E2E UI tests.

The problem is: if we are not connected to the machine with RDP the tests always failed, because the screen of the application (exe) is not matching the resolution of Azure VM.

The VM screen resultion is 1024 x 768, we need to adjust it.. can this be done?

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/1c215514-aeef-41d9-b47b-5c838a0bf83f/how-to-change-the-vm-default-screen-resolution?forum=WAVirtualMachinesforWindows

Answer (score 0):

By Modifying the Registry Editor, you can set the required screen resolution in the Azure VM (Windows). Below is the path traversal to change the resolution in the registry editor:

1. Run Command > regedit

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Video\GUID\0000\DefaultSettings.XResolution
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Video\GUID\0000\DefaultSettings.YResolution
```

[image]